# SNS failed to warn about a missing variable in a SES Templated email

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I had a SES templated email with a line looking line this:

`<h6>Welcome {{usernamee}}</h6>`

My emails were never being sent and it took me forever to see I had a typo in my template.

I am using AWS SDK for Java 2.x (version 2.20.153 to be exact) and the response from AWS return 200 OK.

Looking around, SNS seems to be the one would should tell me when the rendering of the email has failed. I have a SNS with a simple lambda that will tell me when the email has either bounced or been delivery successfully, but no rendering error ever surfaced

Lamda:

```js
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
    console.log('Message received from SNS:', message);
};
```

Here's the rest of my configuration for my SNS:

```hcl
resource "aws_sns_topic" "ses_topic" {
  name = "ses-topic"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "ses_sns_notification_sender" {
  filename      = "lambdas/ses-sns-notification-sender.zip"
  function_name = "ses-sns-notification-sender"
  role          = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn
  handler       = "ses-sns-notification-sender.handler"
  runtime       = "nodejs14.x"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "ses_sns_notification_sender_subscription" {
  topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.ses_topic.arn
  protocol  = "lambda"
  endpoint  = aws_lambda_function.ses_sns_notification_sender.arn
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_sns" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromSNS"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.ses_sns_notification_sender.function_name
  principal     = "sns.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_sns_topic.ses_topic.arn
}

resource "aws_ses_identity_notification_topic" "email_notification" {
  count                    = length(var.sns_notification_type) // ["Bounce", "Complaint", "Delivery"]
  topic_arn                = aws_sns_topic.ses_topic.arn
  notification_type        = var.sns_notification_type[count.index]
  identity                 = var.ses_identity
  include_original_headers = true
}
```

Comment: How are you actually sending the email via SES? I think the error would have come back from the SES API call, and whatever code performed that call didn't handle the error response. I don't think this is something those SNS triggers would have been notified of at all.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the fact that I use AWS SDK for Java 2.x. Didn't think it would be relevant. Tell me if I need to include anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [the SES docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-personalized-email-api.html):

> If you send an email that contains invalid personalization content,
> Amazon SES might accept the message, but won't be able to deliver it.
> For this reason, if you plan to send personalized email, you should
> configure Amazon SES to send Rendering Failure event notifications
> through Amazon SNS. When you receive a Rendering Failure event
> notification, you can identify which message contained the invalid
> content, fix the issues, and send the message again.

Comment: I've seen this doc and I wasn't able to make it work. It says to subscribe to the SNS topic and 'complete the procedure' (add rights). If you look up my code code, you will see that my lambda is already subscribed to said topic. If it is so, that I already the works since I am getting all the others messages. So this leads me no where.

Comment: What about dead letter queue - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function#dead_letter_config - that a good candidate for errors?

Comment: Been a while now isn't it? Well, that dead letter queue configuration did not work. I tried with sns and sqs, did not receive anything.